# Folding file-specific macros in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, code-folding

What is the best way to have AUCTeX fold some math macros specifically for one file? For example in this very trivial example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\foo}{\lambda}
\begin{document}
$\foo$
\end{document}
```

I would like to tell AUCTeX that in this document and this document only, the fold commands (`C-c C-o C-b` and the such) should fold the macro \foo in math mode to the string "λ". I tried adding the following to the file:

```
% Local Variables:
% eval: (add-to-list 'LaTeX-fold-math-spec-list '("λ" ("foo")))
% End:
```

But it didn't work. First the change was permanent, ie. not local to this file, and second the code was evaluated after the fold-mode was activated, and therefore I needed to reload the file to see the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
% eval: (add-to-list 'LaTeX-fold-math-spec-list '("λ" ("foo")))
```

use

```
% eval: (add-to-list (make-variable-buffer-local 'LaTeX-fold-math-spec-list) '("λ" ("foo")))
% eval: (TeX-fold-mode 1)
```

The first line makes `LaTeX-fold-math-spec-list` buffer local and adds the custom element to the alist, the second one re-activates the folding mode.

Comment: @nik it's due to the `eval`, but you already use an `eval` in your code so I supposed that you alreade made it safe.  Customize [`enable-local-eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html).